# How to create dynamic data ranges by selecting different values from data validation dropdowns?

Tags: excel

I have a table like below:

`Col A | Col B | Col C | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Metric 3
    P       A       X      145        234        324
    P       A       Y      453        324        898
    P       A       Z      329        684        325
    P       B       X      563        349        438
    P       B       Y      237        398        679
    P       B       Z      314        722        227
    P       C       X      636        828        889
    P       C       Y      181        818        338
    P       C       Z      145        234        324
    Q       A       X      145        234        324
    Q       A       Y      123        456        789
    Q       A       Z      329        684        325
    Q       B       X      563        349        438
    Q       B       Y      237        398        679
    Q       B       Z      314        722        227
    Q       C       X      636        828        889
    Q       C       Y      181        818        338
    Q       C       Z      145        234        324`

Values are dummy under the Metrics. This sheet is called "Raw".

There is another sheet which I am calling "View" where I have created two dropdown options using Data Validation for Col B and Col C.

What I need help is on getting the output with the data range based on the selected values in dropdowns. In the example below:

`Col B   A`
`Col C   Y`

If selected values in Col B is 'A' and for Col C is 'Y', we need the output range to look like below:

`Col A | Col B | Col C | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Metric 3
   P       A       Y        453        324       898
   Q       A       Y        123        456       789`

I want to be able to have this output range changed if the values from dropdown are changed.

I hope the requirement is understandable. Please let me know should you need further details.
One way is to use lookups but that is taking a lot of time since I have 15 columns for metrics and thousands of rows. I specifically need help in finding a faster solution.

Comment: could you use in C2, =IF(AND(A2="A", B2="Y"), 453)
Of course you need to do similar formulas for D2 and E2
and you need some nested if conditions for other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your results table, Under metric 1, use this formula

```
K2 =INDEX(D$1:D$19,SUMPRODUCT(($A1:$A19=$H2)*($B1:$B19=$I2)*($C1:$C19=$J2)*ROW($B1:$B19)))
```

Here `A:A` is `colA`, `B:B` is `colB`, `C:C` is colC and D:D has the data for `Metric1`.

`H2` is the validation cell for `colA`, `I2` is the validation cell for `colB`, and `J2` is the validation cell for `colC`

Drag this for all your metrics.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your help. I think I need to modify the question a bit, because I am not clear with the references in the formula. Can you please review it once more?

Comment: revised my formula. The principle is still the same and I get your desired result